# What is MDID for?

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, images, attribute

When i add an image to the content of the email i see a mdid attribute being assigned to the image.
What is the use of this mdid and what if i remove this?

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" align="center">
    <img id="image-placeholder" src="http://image.s4.exct.net/lib/xxx/m/1/xxx.jpg" border="0" title="Apartment" mdid="98cc113d-ce65-4e82-ba2c-927511d4788c" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDID stands for Metadata ID.

It's used to identify or refer this particular image element with a unique ID.
Marketing Cloud probably uses it with it's own API events. Would advise to keep it in place and unmodified.